SLL downgrade attack - How to enforce SSL version with flask and the requests library
Recently I set up a simple flask backend, which uses TLS. Now I wanted to simulate a SSL downgrade attack and faced some challenges. My client is simulated with the requests library. To setup the TLS connection, I simply used the following code.
Flask Backend:
import ssl
from flask import Flask
...
# Initialize flaskserver with potential SSL Client Authentication
# Same effect with ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_3  
flask_app = Flask(__name__)    
std_ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(protocol=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER) 
std_ssl_context.load_cert_chain(conf_dict["SERV_CERT_P"],conf_dict["SERV_KEY_P"])
flask_app.run(host=conf_dict["FLASK_IP"], port=conf_dict["FLASK_PORT"], ssl_context=std_ssl_context)

Requests Client:
import requests
from ssl import TLSVersion
from requests.adapters import Retry
from requests_toolbelt.adapters import SourceAddressAdapter
...
class SSLSourceAdressAdapter(SourceAddressAdapter):
    """"Transport adapter" that allows us to use SSLv3."""
    def __init__(self, source_address, ssl_vers, **kwargs):
        self.ssl_version = ssl_vers
        super().__init__(source_address, **kwargs)
                
    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(
            num_pools=connections, maxsize=maxsize,
            block=block, ssl_version=self.ssl_version)

class SslClient:
    def __init__(self, config = TEST_CONF_DICT, cert_p = None, key_p = None, source_adapt = None):
        # Read from Config
        if cert_p is None or key_p is None:
            self.ssl_context = (config["CLI_CERT_P"], config["CLI_KEY_P"])
        else:
            self.ssl_context = (cert_p, key_p)
        self.config = config
        self.source_ip = config["CLI_IP"]
        self.caCert = config["CA_CERT_P"]
        self.serverPath = 'https://' + config["FLASK_IP"] + f':{config["FLASK_PORT"]}'
        self.resources = config["RESOURCES"]
        # Initialize Clientconnection specifics
        s = requests.Session()
        if source_adapt is None:
            # Only try once, for faster testing
            retries = Retry(total=1)
            source_adapt = SourceAddressAdapter(self.source_ip,max_retries=retries)
        s.mount('https://', source_adapt)
        self.sess = s

   def send_get (self, subPath,headers=None,params=None) -> requests.Response:
        return self.sess.get(url=self.serverPath + f'{subPath}', verify=self.caCert, \
            cert=self.ssl_context, headers=headers,params=params)
...
SslClient(config=client.config, source_adapt=SSLSourceAdressAdapter(source_address=client.source_ip,ssl_vers=TLSVersion.SSLv3,max_retries=Retry(total=1)))

Now even though I defined SSL 3 with ssl.TLSVersion.SSLv3 for the Client in requests.Session() and the server uses ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER or ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_3 in the SSLContext of the flask.app, the communication is performed through TLS1.2, which I could observe through Wireshark.
Questions

How can I enforce the Client to use SSL3 and the Server to use TLS
1.3?
What could be other alternatives to simulate the downgrade attack?


what are SourceAddressAdapter and SSLSourceAdressAdapter?

Where in the client do you specify to use SSL version 3?

Hey I added the missing imports and the class SSLSourceAdressAdapter. This is a way of setting the SSL version for a requests client, as stated in https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#example-specific-ssl-version . I set the SSL version with the same class in the last line with ssl_vers=TLSVersion.SSLv3.
